# Avoid session hijacking

Tags: java, servlets

I am using code below to avoid session hijacking. 
I am able to login successfully, when I am performing any other operation after login, then it destroys my session and asks for login again.

Please suggest, what am I doing wrong and what should I do to avoid session hijacking.

```xml
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
    <!--     <http-only>true</http-only> -->
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<http-only> true </http-only>` tag should be un commented. Also same behavior can be achieved on java side like

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // perform login checks and other validations

    String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();

    response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid
            + "; Path=" + contextPath + "; HttpOnly; Secure");

    response.sendRedirect("/some path");
}
```